# List of Maple kernel functions

Tags: maple

There's a set of functions which don't show their code with `print` when one uses `interface(verboseproc=2)`. These are implemented in Maple kernel.

Is there a list of such functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try issuing the command,

```
anames(builtin);
```

This approach is documented on the [type,builtin](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=type/builtin) help-page.